# Javascript Function only Running once

Tags: javascript, function, css

I am working on an animated CSS3 gradient with Javascript, and it works... Just only once. Ithink it has something to do with the variables "percent1" and "percent2". i can't figure out my error, it would be nice if someone could point it out:

```
 function gradient() {
    var styles = document.getElementById("write"),
        styles2 = document.getElementById("write2"),
        percent1 = 0,
        percent2 = 0;

    styles.innerHTML = "<style> \n.liItem { \nbackground: linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -moz-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -webkit-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -o-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%);\n}\n </style>";
    styles2.innerHTML = "";
    var liItem = new Array(document.getElementsByClassName("LiItem")[0], document.getElementsByClassName("LiItem")[1], document.getElementsByClassName("LiItem")[2]);

    liItem[0].onmouseover = function() {
        var liItemNumber = 0;
        var percent1 = 0,
            percent2 = 0;
        liItem[liItemNumber].className = liItem[liItemNumber].className + " liItemNumber";
        //window.alert(liItemNumber);
        interval1 = setInterval(animate, 5);
    }
        liItem[1].onmouseover = function() {
        var liItemNumber = 1;
        var percent1 = 0,
            percent2 = 0;
        liItem[liItemNumber].className = liItem[liItemNumber].className + " liItemNumber";
        //window.alert(liItemNumber);
        interval1 = setInterval(animate, 5);
    }
    liItem[2].onmouseover = function() {
        var liItemNumber = 2;
        var percent1 = 0,
            percent2 = 0;
        liItem[liItemNumber].className = liItem[liItemNumber].className + " liItemNumber";
        //window.alert(liItemNumber);
        interval1 = setInterval(animate, 5);
    }

    function animate() {
        if ((percent1 == 0) && (percent2 >= 0  && percent2 <= 5)) {
            styles2.innerHTML = "";
            percent2 = percent2 + 5;
        styles2.innerHTML = "<style> \n.liItemNumber { \nbackground: linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -moz-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -webkit-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -o-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%);\n}\n </style>";
        }
        else if ((percent1 >= 0) && (percent2 >= 5  && percent2 <= 100)) {
            styles2.innerHTML = "";
            percent2 = percent2 + 5;
            percent1 = percent1 + 5;
        styles2.innerHTML = "<style> \n.liItemNumber { \nbackground: linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -moz-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -webkit-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -o-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%);\n}\n </style>";
        }
        else if ((percent1 >= 95 && percent1 <=100) && (percent2 == 100)) {
            styles2.innerHTML = "";
            percent1 = percent1 + 5;
        styles2.innerHTML = "<style> \n.liItemNumber { \nbackground: linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -moz-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -webkit-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%); \nbackground: -o-linear-gradient(325deg, #FFD176 " + percent1 + "%, #85aaff " + percent2 + "%);\n}\n </style>";
        }
        else if ((percent1 == 100) && (percent2 == 100)) {
            styles2.innerHTML = "";
        liItem[liItemNumber].className = "";
        liItem[liItemNumber].className = "liItem";
        clearInterval(interval1);
        }
        else {
            styles2.innerHTML = "";
        clearInterval(interval1);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Reset `percent1` and `percent2` to 0 in this case: `else if ((percent1 == 100) && (percent2 == 100))`

Comment: Yeah, maybe the values of the variables are not what you expect. [Learn how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), set a breakpoint, inspect the variables and you will find out!

Comment: Are you redefining `percent1` and `percent2` in your event handlers on purpose?  This creates new temporary local variables that have nothing to do with the other ones in the gradient function.  If you didn't intend for that, then remove the `var` in front of the variables inside the mouseover event handlers.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue, jfriend00. it worked